# SKLabelNode not following performSelector (setHidden) with 64 bit iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios7, 32bit-64bit

I am using sprite kit and I have an SKLabelNode that I set up in my initWithSize method.  It is declared as..

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) SKLabelNode *chargesToShowUponCompletion;
```

In the initWithSize method I create it this way..

```
_chargesToShowUponCompletion = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];
_chargesToShowUponCompletion.fontSize = 40;
_chargesToShowUponCompletion.fontColor = [SKColor whiteColor];
_chargesToShowUponCompletion.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, 1.5/3.0 * self.size.height);
_chargesToShowUponCompletion.zPosition = 20;
[self addChild:_chargesToShowUponCompletion];
[_chargesToShowUponCompletion setHidden:YES];
```

As you can see, I hide the LabelNode right after I have added it to the scene.  I actually have several that I create like this, and I reveal them a different times.  This one in particular needs to be shown for a bit, then disappear.  So to accomplish that I have used the following.

```
[_chargesToShowUponCompletion performSelector:@selector(setHidden:) withObject:@YES afterDelay:3];
```

This works perfectly in iPhone 5, iPhone 4, and the simulator.  However, when I run it on a 64 bit machine, or simulator, it does not work.  It actually works as if I had setHidden withObject:@NO.  I am figuring it has something to do with the 64 vs 32 bit iPhones, but I can not figure it out.  I read Apple's doc about supporting both and I have my Architectures set for Standard.  Is there some way I can get this selector to run on both types of machines?  Also, the other LabelNodes that I create are hidden and shown at various times, they all work, but none of them deals with the selector.  Any ideas? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if any one is following this, or having the same problem, I solved it two different ways.  The first one was to keep the @selector(setHidden) line of code. I replaced the @YES with @(1l) and this solved the problem of running on 5s.

```
[_chargesToShowUponCompletion performSelector:@selector(setHidden:) withObject:@(1l) afterDelay:3];  //change @YES to @(1l)
[_substanceToShowUponCompletion performSelector:@selector(setHidden:) withObject:@(1l) afterDelay:3];
```

UPDATE:  I have heard it is bad to use performSelector in this manner. I would just go with the run block.

The other method was to make an SKAction run Block like this.

```
SKAction *action1 = [SKAction waitForDuration:3.0];

SKAction *action2 = [SKAction runBlock:^{
    _chargesToShowUponCompletion.hidden = YES;}];

SKAction *action3 = [SKAction runBlock:^{
 _substanceToShowUponCompletion.hidden = YES;}];

SKAction *seq1 = [SKAction sequence:@[action1, action2]];
SKAction *seq2 = [SKAction sequence:@[action1, action3]];

[_chargesToShowUponCompletion runAction:seq1];
[_substanceToShowUponCompletion runAction:seq2];
```

I ran that twice as well since I had two SKLabelnodes to hide.  Hope this helps someone!!!!